# Getting element names/values with XML/Xpath/PHP

Tags: php, xml, getelementsbytagname

I have an XML schema that looks as follows:

```
<xml>
  <user id="1">
    <first_name>Bill</first_name>
    <last_name>Steve</last_name>
    <phone_numbers>
      <work>xxx-xxx-xxxx</work>
      <home>xxx-xxx-xxxx</home>
    </phone_numbers>
   </user>
   <user id="2">
      ........
   </user>
</xml>
```

Im working on parsing all of this information into PHP using DOM.  Ex.

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
foreach($userInfo as $row)
{
       $first_name = $row->getElementsByTagName("first_name");
}
```

When I try to nest this to select the phone numbers however I get an error.  I've tried using XPath to select the phone numbers with equal problems.  I tried something along the lines of

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
foreach($userInfo as $row)
{
       $phoneInfo = $row->getElementsByTagName("phone_numbers");
       foreach($phoneInfo as $row2)
       {
            $work = $row2->getElementsByTagName("work");
       }
}
```

Im curious if Im doing something fundamentally wrong, or how to get this going.  I've been tearing my hair out for a few hours now.

Comment: Works for me! Which PHP do you use?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList`. Are you sure you can iterate through it using foreach? (Just asking)

Comment: There is no XPath usage in question. Retagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the value directly from a DOMNodeList Object, try this :

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
foreach($userInfo as $row)
{
       $phoneInfo = $row->getElementsByTagName("phone_numbers");
       foreach($phoneInfo as $row2)
       {
            // get the value from the first child
            $work = $row2->getElementsByTagName("work")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $home = $row2->getElementsByTagName("home")->item(0)->nodeValue;
       }
}
```

Comment: I want to kiss you on the mouth right now.  That worked like a charm.  I love/hate it when it's so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could switch it to [SimpleXml](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which  makes this type of parsing easier:

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
foreach ($userInfo as $user) {
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($user);
    $id = (string) $node['id'];
    $first = (string) $node->first_name;
    $last = (string) $node->last_name;
    $workPhone = (string) $node->phone_numbers->work;
    $homePhone = (string) $node->phone_numbers->home;
}
```

Now, in DomDocument, you could do this by using [`DomXpath`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
foreach ($userInfo as $user) {
    $id = $user->getAttribute('id');
    $first = $xpath->query('//first_name', $user)->item(0)->textContent;
    $last = $xpath->query('//last_name', $user)->item(0)->textContent;
    $work = $xpath->query('//phone_numbers/work', $user)->item(0)->textContent;
    $home = $xpath->query('//phone_numbers/home', $user)->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

Note that the above code (both parts) require that the format is exactly that.  If you have conditionals, you might want to change it to something like this (the `firstname` conditional only):

```
$userInfo = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user" ); 
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
foreach ($userInfo as $user) {
    $id = $user->getAttribute('id');
    $firstQuery = $xpath->query('//first_name', $user);
    if ($firstQuery->length > 0) {
        $first = $firstQuery->item(0)->textContent;
    } else {
        $first = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use DomXpath as you mentioned here, but the problem I was having was differentiating which user was associated with the phone number.  It looks like using xpath onside the object returned from $userInfo would work, I hadn't thought of that.  The other answer more closely hits what I need, but this looks really solid.  Thanks for taking the time out to help and when I dig into xpath again Im sure I'll use this.